# How to detect if 90% of body collide in Godot 2d

Tags: godot

**I want to change position of player which is rotating when it is 90% collide with door**

Comment: I think you mean overlap instead of collide? anyways, unless your shape is something simple like a square or a circle etc it would be difficult to calculate 90% of that shape, instead maybe you can customly create another Area2D node and when it is 100% overlapped you can change the position of the character? not enough data given in the question, could you add some diagrams and/or code maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use distance_to()
or distance_squared_to() and get the position between object a and the area position